# TwitchLib EventSub Websockets using WinForms .NET 6

Tags: winforms, websocket, .net-6.0, twitch, twitch-api

I'm looking at the documentation for the TwitchLib library EventSub using WebSockets and the examples they have are for either a console app or a WPF app:
https://github.com/TwitchLib/TwitchLib.EventSub.Websockets

My situation, however, is that I have an application already built using WinForms on .NET 6 and want to include the EventSub in there but I can't get it to work when I try creating it in a dummy WinForms project.

I can get their sample console application to work just fine and am currently using IPC Named Ports to make it talk with my WinForms application but I'd prefer to not have to launch a completely separate console app every time my application is launched.